# ingresar varios datos y como evitar que se repita el mismo valor de un checkbox c#

Tags: c#

tengo mi programa en el cual al momento que yo ingrese un cliente se debe de guardar en un archivo de texto y despues hacer otro registro pero noce como hacer eso ya que solo me registra uno y cuando selecciono un dato de un checkbox si me lo muestra pero ya cuando ingreso otro me vuelve a repetir el mismo valor y noce como evitar eso y tengo 4 botones el primer boton es el de agregar me va ir permitiendo agregar un producto el otro boton borrar un producto y el de terminar es que ya haya terminado el pedido mostrar si esta de acuerdo con su pedido o no y es cuando ahi me lo va a guardar en un archivo de texto y el ultimo deberá acumular la ventas hechas a los clientes y permitirá mostrar estas vetas
acumuladas por día  y esto es lo que llevo de mi codigo solo que no estoy usando BD

```
 double sum=0;
        String res,ingre;
        double Total = 0;
        double po = 0;
        string nombre;
        string direccion;
        int telefono;
        int noPizzas;
        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Campos vacios");
            }
            else
            {
                nombre = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
                direccion = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
                telefono = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
                noPizzas = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            }
                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    Total = +40;
                    res = "Chica";
```

}
                    if (radioButton2.Checked)
                    {
                        Total = +80;
                        res = "Mediana";
                }

```
                if (radioButton3.Checked)
                {
                    Total = +120;
                    res += "Grande";
                }

                if (checkBox1.Checked==true)
                {
                    Total = Total + 10;
                    ingre += "Jamon";
                }

            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
                {
                    Total = Total + 20;
                    ingre += "Piña";
                }               
            if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
                {
                    Total = Total + 30;
                    ingre = "Champiñones";
            }
            else
            {                  
                Total = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text) * Total;

                listBox1.Items.Add("Tamaño: " + res + "\t" + "Ingredientes: " + ingre + " , " + "\t" + "No Pizzas: " + noPizzas + "\t" + "Sub Total: " + Total.ToString("c2"));
                sum = sum + Total;
            }            
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < listBox1.Items.Count; c++)
            {
                if (listBox1.GetSelected(c))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(c);
                }
            }
        }   
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            textBox5.Text +="Nombre: " + nombre + "\t"+ "Total: "+ sum;
            po = po + sum;
            textBox5.Text = "Ventas totales por dia: " + po;
        }
        StreamWriter archivo;
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea realizar el pago ? \n Tu total de tu pedido es $" + sum, "Facturacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pago realizado");
                archivo = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\Yuki Misaki\\Desktop\\Nueva carpeta (5)\\archivo.txt");

                foreach (object lista in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    archivo.WriteLine(fecha+ "\t" + nombre+ "\t" + direccion+ "\t" + telefono+ "\t" + lista.ToString());
                }                 
            }
            else                 
            {
                archivo.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Pago NO realizado");

                listBox1.Items.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque usas un archivo de texto como base de datos? no seria mas simple si usas una db, aunque sea Sql Compact o Sqlite. Un archivo requiere parsear los datos de cada linea para trabajarlo, con una db puede hacer select, insert, update sobre una tabla, es mucho mas simple

Comment: de hecho pero esque lo malo esque asi me lo pidieron con un archivo de texto :c

Comment: a que te refieres cuand dices: " cuando selecciono un dato de un checkbox" a que checkbox haces referencia? en el codigo que nos muestras hay eventos de botones, pero no hay ninguno de un checkbox

Comment: en el primer boton ahi pongo un if(checkbox1.checked==true) esque cuando selecciono dos ahi todo bien el problema es cuando quiero agregar otro producto me agrega los otros dos checkbox ya seleccionados

Comment: voy a poner una imagen para que veas que es alo que me refiero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que noto es que usas el `File.CreateText()` para crear el archivo y eso esta bien si la idea es pisar siempre los datos, pero si vas agregar informacion al mismo deberias utilizar

[File.AppendAllLines()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netframework-4.8)

la idea es que agregues lineas a las ya existentes, asi no pisas las anteriores

Despues para leer las lineas usa

[File.ReadAllLines()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8)

lo usarias de esta forma

```
string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Yuki Misaki\\Desktop\\Nueva carpeta (5)\\archivo.txt");

List<string> lineas = new List<string>();
foreach (object lista in listBox1.Items)
{
    lineas.Add(fecha+ "\t" + nombre+ "\t" + direccion+ "\t" + telefono+ "\t" + lista.ToString());
}     

File.AppenAllLines(filePath, lineas);
```